# What does "!" mean in scala?

Tags: scala

I am looking at a piece of code with the following:

`graph.vertices.filter(!_._2._1)`

I understand that `_` are wildcard characters in `scala` but I do not know what the `!` is supposed to do.

What does `!` mean in scala?

Comment: like in most other languages, `!` = "logical not"

Comment: What makes you think it is Akka's `tell`? Since the code is inside a `filter`, I think assuming it to be the "logical not" makes more sense. Also, if it was Akka's  `tell`, it wouldn't compile, because that one needs an `ActorRef` on the left hand side. Second of all, the `_` is not a wildcard in this example. It is the current `vertex`.

Comment: Like Marc said. For example, you can write `Seq("foo", "bar", "").filter(_.isEmpty)`, or `Seq("foo", "bar", "").filter(!_.isEmpty)` or equivalently `Seq("foo", "bar", "").filter(x => !x.isEmpty)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scala doesn't have operators at the syntax level. All operations are methods.

For example, there is no add operator in the syntax, but numbers have a `+` method:

```
2.+(3)   // result is 5
```

When you write `2 + 3`, that's actually syntax sugar for the expression above.

Any type can define a `unary_!` method, which is what `!something` gets desugared to. Booleans implement it, with the obvious meaning of logical negation ("not") that the exclamation mark has in other languages with C heritage.

In your question, the expression is an abbreviated form of the following call:

```
graph.vertices.filter { t => !(t._2._1) }
```

where `t` is a tuple-of-tuples, for which *the first element of the second element* has a type that implements `unary_!` and (as required by `.filter`) returns a `Boolean`. I would bet the money in my pocket that the element itself is a `Boolean`, in which case **`!` just means "not."**

Answer (score 0):

As Robert said, `!` is a method name. It can be tricky determining *which* `!` method is being used.  For example, in the line of code:

```
val exitValue = command.!(ProcessLogger(stdoutWriter.println, stderrWriter.println))
```

where `command` is a `String` (or `Seq`), `command` can be *implicitly* converted to a [ProcessBuilder](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.html), so its `!` method would apply. Your IDE may be able to help.  IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate was able to tell me where `!` was defined.